# I have no firewall2 file

Tags: security, opensuse, firewalld

I have firewall2.d but no firewall2 file. I am trying to set up a lamp server but all the directions I get are for firewall2 "no d". I looked into firewall2.d but it doesn't have what they are referring to the code they refer to in the tutorial. It appears that I need firewall2 with "no d" in order to work my way through this tutorial. I also need to have it to set up the protection.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably find a copy in `/usr/share/doc/packages/SuSEfirewall2/`.

Having "someapplication" and "someapplication.d" is a frequent pattern, where "someapplication" will include configuration-snippets from the "someapplication.d"-directory.

Comment: Thank you for your input on this subject but, the SuSefirewall2 does not exist any longer. It has been replaced with firewalld.

Comment: `/usr/share/doc/packages/firewalld/` then?